# Which way is better to create android view ?

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

Which way  is better   to create android view ?  by using xml or bay using  java code into activity ?

Example :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/account_bundle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/account"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/account_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|end"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="80"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have the choice to create this linearLayout with xml and java into my activity, i want to now which is best solution in term of performance ?

Comment: Rather depends on your use.. I use both types and found almost no difference in performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android framework gives app developer the flexibility to use 1. XML declaration and 2. Instantiate layout elements at runtime for declaring and managing your application's UI

The rationale of using XML approach is that it enables you to better separate the **presentation** of your application from the code that controls its behaviour. Your UI descriptions in XML are external to your application code, which means that you can modify  it without having to modify your source code of your application and recompile.

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) does not mention any performance advantage of one approach over the other.

However, declaring the layout in XML makes it easier to visualize the structure of your UI, so it's easier to debug problems/issues in UI due to separation of UI into xml.

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating static TextViews (color, text size, parent width, etc [for example]) then keep everything in the XML. If you are changing it based on specific information on the application, then it doesn't really matter if its in XML because you will be changing it inside of the code anyway.

Is one way better than the other for performance? no.

I like clean code, so I try not to make a lot of changes in items in my classes.